# Is there a unique boot session id or count on an android device?

Tags: java, android

The app I'm writing needs to know if a '*boot session*', for want of a better term, has changed but it doesn't need to actually start at boot and I would prefer if possible not to have to use the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission.

So I was wondering if there is any device-wide boot session id or count I can query and store in my db to check against later. I know I can get the time in milliseconds since boot but I don't think that will be useful in this case.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How about using [`randomUUID()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID())? The chances of getting two identical UUIDs should be microscopical.

Comment: As the root filesystem is typically a ramdisk, it's creation date tends to be effectively a boot timestamp.

Comment: So have you found boot session id or count?

Comment: Sorry for no reply... but (maybe) better late than never. I haven't used this site or done android app development for a long time, so I have nothing really to add, but no, I don't think I ever found one. Just worked with timestamps in my db as far as I recall.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Why not store the (absolute) date and time of the last boot in your database? You can compute it easily using the time since boot, and given that a boot takes much longer than a millisecond it should be fairly accurate.

Comment: Be wary that time since last boot reported by system may jump on many android devices where I tested this solution, producing incorrect boot count.

Comment: This is a bad idea: the user can change the date at any time as she pleases

Answer (score 5):

Yes, on API >= 24.  You can use the [`BOOT_COUNT` global settings variable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#BOOT_COUNT).  To read this, try a snippet like this:

```
int boot_count = Settings.Global.getInt(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                        Settings.Global.BOOT_COUNT);
```

Pre-API 24, you're stuck catching `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`.

Answer (score 2):

I use this code to get a unique boot ID on all versions of Android. For Nougat and later, I use `Settings.Global.BOOT_COUNT`. For versions older than Nougat, I read a unique boot ID from "/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id". I haven't had any issues with file access on Android 5 in my testing. Tested on Android 5, 8, 9, and 11 on real devices with a release build of our app.

This does not rely on the system clock, which can jump around or be changed by the user.

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46959370/9383288) from @george-hilliard for the `Settings.Global.BOOT_COUNT` solution.

```java
String bootId = "";

if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N ) { // Starting in Android 7 / N(ougat) / API Level 24, we have access to `Settings.Global.BOOT_COUNT`, which increments with every boot.
  bootId = Settings.Global.getString( getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.BOOT_COUNT );
}
else { // Before Android 7 / N(ougat) / API Level 24, we need to get the boot id from the /proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id file. Example boot_id: "691aa77e-aff4-47c2-829e-a34df426c7e7".
 File bootIdFile = new File( "/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id" );

  if ( bootIdFile.exists() ) {
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
      inputStream           = new FileInputStream( bootIdFile );
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( inputStream ) );
      bootId                = reader.readLine().trim(); // Read first line of file to get the boot id and remove any leading and trailing spaces.
    }
    catch ( FileNotFoundException error ) {
      error.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch ( IOException error ) {
      error.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
      if ( inputStream != null ) try { inputStream.close(); } catch (IOException error ) { error.printStackTrace();; }
    }
  }
}

if ( bootId == "" ) {
  Log.e( "UniqueTag", "Could not retrieve boot ID. Build.VERSION.SDK_INT: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT );
}
```